# How to get valgrind to cooperate with libsigsegv?

Tags: segmentation-fault, valgrind

As noted in [this question about using libsigsegv to detect multiple stack overflows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013806), I'm working with a colleague to try to detect and recover from stack overflow in an interpreter.  In brief,

1. We set up a stack-overflow handler using `libsigsegv`.
2. The handler leaves via `sigsegv_leave_handler()`, which then returns to the interpreter's main loop via `siglongjmp`.

This setup successfully detects the first stack overflow, but the second stack overflow leads to a bus error.  I would like to hit this problem with valgrind, but valgrind takes over at the *first* segfault.  My question is, therefore
**how can I get `valgrind` to let `libsigsegv` handle the first segfault, *then* take over memory checking?**

Comment: Arn't thay open source? So you could modify them to ignore the first segfault. But I have no clue how to do it. Thats why it is not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Valgrind is the wrong tool to debug this problem -- you are likely suffering not from heap corruption (which is what Valgrind is great at), but from something else.

I would use GDB to debug this. When you hit the first `SIGSEGV`, GDB will stop. You can ask it to deliver the signal to the application with `(gdb) signal SIGSEGV`, at which point your interpreter will execute the `siglongjmp`. Eventually you'll get `SIGBUS`, and can debug how you got there.

Since you are likely on Linux, note that `SIGBUS` is rather rare, and usually results from trying to access memory that is either not mapped at all, or with wrong protections. Examining `/proc/<pid>/maps` at the point where `SIGBUS` is delivered will likely help.